# Syntax error with Rails 3 new form helper and ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm using a pre-commit hook for Git that checks the syntax of my files before I can commit them.

In a Rails 3 app (I'm using the new form helper's syntax : `<%= form_for @article do |f| %>` but I get a syntax error, not when I use the app, but when I check for the syntax through the ruby CLI command or the Textmate's bundle command.

The command that is executed is `erb -xT - #{file} | ruby -c` so it goes through `erb` before `ruby`. If I change the `erb` binary to `erubis`, I get the same error.

I've tried to create a blank Rails3 app, with a generic scaffold, and the result is exactly the same.

I've also tried this with REE 1.8.7 2010.02, 1.8.7-p174, 1.9.2-preview3, … and I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
"sed 's/<%=/<%/g' #{file} | erb -xT - | ruby -c"
```

(Replaces all <%= tags with <% for the syntax check, which is good enough for a syntax check.)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it complaining about the `<%=` instead of `<%` used in rails 2.x versions?

what exactly is the error you get?